# Incremental code deployment to a large cluster in the cloud

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, chef-infra, puppet

How can I do incremental deployment of my code to a large cluster in the cloud? I mean if I have a cluster of say 300 nodes and I want that cluster to get updated with my latest build code but only on the files that are changed (binary and data files), how can I go about it?

I came across murder but it doesn't seem to do incremental file deployment and copies everything down to every node.

I also looked at chef but that does not seem to be a good fit for incremental total code deployment too and it is more suitable to run your installer on every machine and make sure the installed code config files are up to date according to the chef server. It does not look like to bother with the version of the installed program. So I see chef have file control but maybe make sense to use it for a config file but not sure if it makes sense for a code project that has hundred of binaries and data files.

I can sure write my own system to do this but I am wondering if I have a better option for large cluster incremental deployment especially during the development phase?

In my case, the servers are windows and cloud is aws.

Comment: The first thing you need to think about is if your code is able to run the old and new version of the code at the same time ("rolling upgrade"), if not this whole discussion does not make a lot of sense. To have that ability your code and your protocols need to be designed accordingly.

Comment: Sorry not following you. How is that related? Imagine I want the code on my cluster be stay up to date with the latest code of specific branch but I want the cluster to only deploy the binary and data files that have changed. No everything from scratch so that it will be a quick deployment everytime the source code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [kwatee](http://Www.kwatee.net) (I'm affiliated). It is a lightweight and fully free tool. Among other things it automatically does incremental deployments by comparing the hash of each file against that of what is deployed.

Comment: This seems to be a limited version of chef? Correct? How are the hash code generated and compared? It looks that it accept a pakage and not a folder of files? Am I right?

Comment: @iCode It is not related to Chef which is more geared at processural infrastructure management but lives in a similar space. Kwatee accepts tar/tgz/bzip/zip archives or simple folders of files. The hashes are generated initially when you upload the package/folder into the repository. Hashes for templatized files (I.e containing variables) are recalculated whenever one of their values changes.